# How Do I load a jquery function dynamically?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm currently working on a Java web application, and have dynamically generated input boxes on the jsp page. I'm trying to use the setupElementMasks() function from http://www.xaprb.com/html-input-mask/html-form-input-mask.js to mask input. My input boxes are generated dynamically so would I have to use jquery's .load function to load the desired function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Description: *Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.*

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what he needs, *now and in the future*.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="/http://www.xaprb.com/html-input-mask/html-form-input-mask.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){

    doworkhere();

});
</script>
```

HTH